# Передача значение переменной в Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Ребят, как передать значение переменной в Sqlite.

Вот код создания колонок в коде, и моя неудачная попытка вставка значений из текстовых полей.

```
EditText Name2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText Number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
Name2.getText().toString();
Number2.getText().toString();
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Rielt",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ONE("+Name+" VARCHAR,"+Number+" Int);");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO ONE VALUES('"+ Name2 +",' "+ Number2 +");");
db.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала надо хотя бы код выделить.
А во-вторых, чуть чуть почить по разработке под андроид.
Я примерно понял, что вам надо, но не факт что заработает

```
 EditText Name2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 EditText Number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
 String name_1 = "name1";//тут посылаете ваше значение
 Sting number_1 = "123";//тут посылаете чило, которое вам надо
 String name_2 =  Name2.getText().toString();
 String number_2 = Number2.getText().toString(); 
 SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Rielt",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ONE("+name_1+" VARCHAR,"+number_1+" Int);");
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO ONE VALUES('"+ name_2 +",' "+ number_2 +");");
 db.close();
```